# How to get the mask amount or percentage in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When applying a mask modifier is it possible to get the amount or percentage of mask that is visible? I'm trying to implement a scratch card view using `Canvas` where I'd like to fully reveal the yellow *content* view after it is say 80% visible.

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
struct ScratchCardView: View {
    @State var points = [CGPoint]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // MARK: Scratchable overlay view
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)

            // MARK: Hidden content view
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(.yellow)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                .mask(
                    Path { path in
                        path.addLines(points)
                    }.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 50, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                )
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            points.append(value.location)
                        })
                        .onEnded({ _ in
                           // TODO: detect content view visibility
                        })
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the area of the stroked portions would be rather difficult. I would approximate this by sampling some points inside the square, and see how many points are inside the stroked portion. From the few tests I did, I feel this is good enough, especially since you have such a large stroke width.

First get the `CGPath` that represents the stroked area:

```
let cgpath = Path { path in
    path.addLines(points)
}.cgPath
// remember to use the same parameters here as you did in the StrokeStyle!
let contourPath = cgpath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 50, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 10)
```

Then, find some points in the square to sample. Here, I've divided the big square into 5*5 smaller squares, and picked the points at the centre of each of those smaller squares.

```
var count = 0
for i in 0..<5 {
    for j in 0..<5 {
        let point = CGPoint(x: 25 + i * 50, y: 25 + j * 50)
        if contourPath.contains(point) {
            count += 1
        }
    }
}
if count > 20 {
    print("More than 75%!")
}
```